How to retain debug this code without removing the link between LinkedList class and TelevisionInventory class
Basically, this is my TelevisionInventory class
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class TelevisionInventory {
    private List<Television> tvList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
    private Stack<Television> tvStack = new Stack<>();
    private Queue<Television> tvQueue = new LinkedList<>(); 
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void runInventorySystem() {
        int option;
        do {
            System.out.println("\nTelevision Inventory System");
            System.out.println("1. Add Television");
            System.out.println("2. Delete Television");
            System.out.println("3. Search and Display");
            System.out.println("4. Display All Televisions");
            System.out.println("5. Calculate");
            System.out.println("6. Move Data to LinkedList");
            System.out.println("7. Display data in LinkedList");
            System.out.println("8. Move data to Stack");
            System.out.println("9. Copy data to Stack");
            System.out.println("10. Display data in Stack");
            System.out.println("11. Move data to Queue");
            System.out.println("12. Copy data to Queue");
            System.out.println("13. Display data in Queue");
            System.out.println("14. Make an Expression Conversion");
            System.out.println("15. Exit");
            System.out.print("Select an option: ");
            option = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    addTelevision();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    deleteTelevision();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    searchAndDisplay();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    displayInventory(tvList, "List of Televisions");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    calculateStats();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    moveDataToLinkedList();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    displayLinkedListData();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    moveDataToStack();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    copyDataToStack();
                    break;
                case 10:
                    displayStackData();
                    break;
                case 11:
                    moveDataToQueue();
                    break;
                case 12:
                    copyDataToQueue();
                    break;
                case 13:
                    displayQueueData();
                    break;
                case 14:
                    expressionConversion();
                    break;
                case 15:
                    System.out.println("Exiting...");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option, please try again.");
                    break;
            }
        } while (option != 15);
        scanner.close();
    }

    private void addTelevision() {
        boolean continueAdding = true;
        while (continueAdding) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter TV ID: ");
            int id = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Brand: ");
            String brand = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Size (in inches): ");
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Is it Digital? (true/false): ");
            boolean isDigital = scanner.nextBoolean();
            System.out.print("Enter Price: ");
            double price = scanner.nextDouble();
            scanner.nextLine();

            Television tv = new Television(id, brand, size, isDigital, price);
            tvList.add(tv);
            System.out.println("Television added successfully!");

            System.out.print("Do you want to add another TV? (true/false): ");
            continueAdding = scanner.nextBoolean();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }

    private void deleteTelevision() {
        System.out.print("Enter TV ID to delete: ");
        int id = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < tvList.size(); i++) {
            if (tvList.get(i).getId() == id) {
                tvList.remove(i);
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Television with ID " + id + " has been removed.");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("No television with ID " + id + " found.");
        }
    }

    private void searchAndDisplay() {
        System.out.print("Enter TV ID or name to search: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        Television searchedTv = null;

        try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(input);

            for (Television tv : tvList) {
                if (tv.getId() == id) {
                    searchedTv = tv;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            for (Television tv : tvList) {
                if (tv.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                    searchedTv = tv;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (searchedTv != null) {
            System.out.println("Found Television: " + searchedTv);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Television not found.");
        }
    }

    private void displayInventory(List<Television> inventory, String type) {
        if (inventory.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(type + " is empty.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(type + " Inventory:");
            inventory.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private void displayLinkedListData() {
        if (linkedList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("LinkedList is empty.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("LinkedList Inventory:");
            System.out.println(linkedList.printList());
        }
    }

    private void calculateStats() {
        if (tvList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No Televisions in inventory.");
            return;
        }

        double sum = 0;
        double avg;
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;

        for (Television tv : tvList) {
            double price = tv.getPrice();

            sum += price;

            if (price < min) {
                min = price;
            }

            if (price > max) {
                max = price;
            }
        }
        avg = sum / tvList.size();
        System.out.println("\nSum: RM " + sum + "\nAverage: RM " + avg + "\nMinimum: RM " + min + "\nMaximum: RM " + max);
    }

    private void moveDataToLinkedList() {
        for (Television tv : tvList) {
            linkedList.insertAtBack(tv);
        }
        tvList.clear();
        System.out.println("Data moved to LinkedList successfully.");
    }

    private void copyDataToStack() {
        for (int i = 0; i < linkedList.size(); i++) {
            try {
                tvStack.push((Television) linkedList.getNext());
            } catch (LinkedList.EmptyListException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Data copied to Stack successfully.");
    }

    private void moveDataToStack() {
        for (Television tv : tvList) {
            tvStack.push(tv);
        }
        tvList.clear();
        System.out.println("Data moved to Stack successfully.");
    }

    private void displayStackData() {
        if (tvStack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Stack Inventory:");
            System.out.println(tvStack);
        }
        }

    private void moveDataToQueue() {
        for (Television tv : tvList) {
            tvQueue.offer(tv);
        }
        tvList.clear();
        System.out.println("Data moved to Queue successfully.");
    }

    private void copyDataToQueue() {
        for (Television tv : tvList) {
            tvQueue.offer(tv);
        }
        System.out.println("Data copied to Queue successfully.");
    }

    private void displayQueueData() {
        if (tvQueue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Queue Inventory:");
            System.out.println(tvQueue);
        }
    }

    private void expressionConversion() {
        System.out.print("Enter infix expression to convert: ");
        String infix = scanner.nextLine();
        String postfix = PostFixConverter.convertToPostFix(infix);
        System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + postfix);
    }
}
 


And this is my LinkedList class
public class LinkedList
{
     private Node head, tail, current;
    //Default LinkedList Class
     public LinkedList() { 
         head = tail = current = null; 
    }
 
     //To check whether is the linked list empty
     public boolean isEmpty() { 
         return head == null; 
    }
 
     // to print data
     public String printList()
     { 
         if (isEmpty())
             return "( empty list )";
         else
             return "(" + head + ")";
     }
 
     //To add new Object data at the front of the LinkedList
     public void insertAtFront(Object data)
     {
         if(isEmpty())
         head = tail = new Node(data);
         else
         head = new Node(data, head);
     }
     // Return the number of elements in the list
     public int size()
     {
         int count = 0;
         if (isEmpty())
             return count;
 
         current = head;
         while(current != null)
         {
             ++count;
             current = current.next;
         }
         return count;
     }
     //To add new Object data at the back of linked list
     public void insertAtBack(Object data)
     {
         if(isEmpty())
             head = tail = new Node(data);
         else
             tail = tail.next = new Node(data);
 
     }
 
     // Return the first element in the linked list 
     public Object getFirst() throws EmptyListException
     {
         if(isEmpty())
         throw new EmptyListException();
 
         current = head;
         return current.data;
     }
 
     // Return the next element in the linked list 
    public Object getNext() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = head;
        } else if (current != tail) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current != null ? current.data : null;
    }
 
     // Return the last element in the linked list 
     public Object getLast() throws EmptyListException
     {
         if(isEmpty())
             throw new EmptyListException();
 
         return tail.data;
     }
     
     // Remove the first element in the linked list
     public Object removeFromFront() throws EmptyListException
     {
         if(isEmpty())
             throw new EmptyListException();
 
             Object d = head.data;
 
         if(head==tail)
             head=tail=null;
         else
        {
             Node curr = head;
             head = head.next;
             curr.next = null;
         }
 
         return d;
 
     }
 
    // Remove the last element in the linked list
     public Object removeFromBack() throws EmptyListException
     {
         if(isEmpty())
             throw new EmptyListException();
 
         Object d = tail.data;
 
         if(head==tail)

         head=tail=null;
         else
        {
         Node curr = head;
         while(curr.next != tail)
         curr = curr.next;
 
         tail = curr;
         curr.next = null;
         }
 
         return d;
     }
     
    public class EmptyListException extends RuntimeException{
        public EmptyListException(){
            super("The list is empty");
        }
    }
}

The problem occurs when in line 11, there's an error only at '<>' part. The compiler that I use said
"cannot infer type of argument for LinkedList. Reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class LinkedList."
Another clue that I think I need to tell is the LinkedList class has a link to the node and LinkedList class is a parent class of Queue class and Stack class. the diagram of relationship between class
So, the question is, is there any way to debug this code without removing the link between TelevisionInventory class and LinkedList class?
I've try to add import.java.util.LinkedList to the TelevisionInventory class. But, the link between them are disappear.
I also tried to just remove the LinkedList class and just put all the code into the TelevisionInventory class. But, the program become too messy and I didn't have an idea where to put the stack class and Queue class.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Your LinkedList must implement Queue<Television> since you try to assign it to a variable of this type.
You can do it like this (by using generics):
public class LinkedList<T> implements Queue<T> {
...
}

Than you need to implement the methods defined for Queue
and you should also change the types of your our own methods to use the generic type T
 public void insertAtBack(T data)
 public T getFirst() throws EmptyListException
 public T getNext() {
 public T getLast() throws EmptyListException
 public T removeFromFront() throws EmptyListException
 public T removeFromBack() throws EmptyListException


REMARK:
Since you assign the LinkedList instance to a variable of type Queue you will only be able to access the methods definded in Queue on it (for the others you would need to cast the type to LinkedList first).
